# Excel language change from local to english - win7

Tags: excel, windows-7, office365, excel-2016, office-2016

I want to change the language in Excel* (office package) from Danish to English on my firm computer with Win7 enterprise**. I have been through online guidelines and changed to:

- [Display language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGR24.png) = English
- [System Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdlJZ.png) = English (USA)
- [Default input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KP0L.png) = English (US)
- [Editing language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/socat.png) (in excel) = English (USA)
- User interface (in excel) = Same as in Microsoft windows
- Help language (in excel) = Same as in User interface

And still my office products remain in local language. So I am out of ideas.

Could some one please assist?

*Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.9126.2259) 64-bit
**windows 7 enterprise - service pack 1

Comment: Hi @JSF This question is better suited for https://superuser.com which is reserved for software help. StackOverflow is primarily for questions about programming.

Comment: StackOverflow is the place for asking software developing problems.  I’d recommend you post your answer here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=excel&filter=alltypes&sort=lastpostdesc